# Change function from to a equal check

Tags: java

How can I change the check variable so that it doesn't check if LastNameField is not empty so that it checks if lastNameField is equal the lastNamefield?

```
private boolean isInputValid() {
    String errorMessage = "";

    if (firstNameField.getText() == null || firstNameField.getText().length() == 0) {
        errorMessage += "No valid German word!\n"; 
    }
    if (lastNameField.getText() == null || lastNameField.getText().length() == 0) {
        errorMessage += "No valid English word!\n"; 
    }

      //if (pw.equals(gpw) == true) {
    if (errorMessage.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // Show the error message.
        Dialogs.create()
            .title("wrong spelling")
            .masthead("Please correct!")
            .message(errorMessage)
            .showError();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: I didnt understand your question

Comment: Do you mean equal to `firstNameField`?

Comment: firstNameField should be checked if it is equal with the firstNameField

Comment: Instead of `s.length() == 0` it is possible to do `s.isEmpty()` since java 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a method to check is field equals something except of is it not empty, use this:

```
if (!"lastNamefield".equals(lastNameField)){
    errotMessage+= "No valid English word!\n";
}
```

Or aks you question correctly, it is really hard to understand, what you want!

Comment: Better to place String literals on the left side of the `.equals` because it avoids NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: Thanks for correction! Now i understand, why netbeans always says me to do this.